# Winston createLogger() is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, winston

In a TypeScript, Node project I am trying to make some Jest unit tests, the problem is ever since I installed Jest with ts-node the main code is broken, when I try to us `npm test` or `npm start` I get this error:

```
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/server.ts`
TypeError: winston_1.default.createLogger is not a function
```

I'm using Winston 3.6.0 but can someone help me?

Comment: what does `src/server.ts` look like?

Comment: it is too long and sadly I don't know if I am allowed to share it, can you specify  the part you need, vscode generated problem is at the include ones, `import logger, { initLogger } from "./logger";` in the  server.ts file and in the logger file `import winston from "winston";` @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
import * as winston from "winston";

const loggerInstance = winston.createLogger({});

loggerInstance.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
loggerInstance.info('Hello again distributed logs');
```